# Алгоритм задачи

Tags: алгоритм, c++

Помогите, пожалуйста, алгоритмом. Не прошу, чтоб решали за меня, а просто подскажите, направьте меня. Вот задача:

> В арифметическом выражении разрешается использовать число 1, операции сложения, умножения и скобки. Какое наименьшее количество единиц нужно использовать, чтобы получить заданное натуральное число n?

Например: Дается 7. (1+1+1)*(1+1)+1 = 7

Сразу скажу, что я делал: хотел делить число на 3. Получить "Множители"(2, 3) и "Остаток"(1)
и составить нужное решение. Однако это не для всех чисел идет. Например для 99. Что посоветуете?

Comment: Т.е можно, например, использовать связку единиц - 11, например?

    разрешается использовать число 1...

Comment: нет. Там же не цифру "1" говорят, а **число** 1

Comment: Навскидку оптимальный алгоритм может быть такой:  
1 может быть представлено как 1
2 может быть представлено как 1+1
Это исходные данные. Далее начинаем последовательно находить как может быть выражено число для 3, 4...
Основополагающими считаем правила, что минимальное число единиц будет использовано, если число выражается как:  
Х+У  
Х* У  
Х+У+1.  
Х*У+1.  
Где Х и У это уже ранее выраженные числа.  
То есть перебор пар уже известных чисел и нахождение минимального числа единиц, которыми можно выразить с учетом четырех формул.

Comment: добавить ещё<br>
X(Y+1)<br>
(X+1)Y

Comment: @sercxjo У+1 и Х+1 это некое другое число Р, которое вероятно может быть выражено меньшим числом единиц. В моем алгоритме кстати Х+У+1 избыточен по той же причине.

Comment: @ReinRaus, X+Y не меняет количество единичек в меньшую сторону, если точнее оставляет прежним, следовательно такое разбиение не приведет к оптимальному, в частности при разбиении 99 по X+Y получим 99 единиц. Оптимальным будет разбиение когда будет как можно больше умножений и как меньше сложений. если число не раскладывается на множители, то максимум что стоит (читай "достаточно") рассматривать это XY+1, которые(X или Y) уж точно делятся на 2. а добавлять больше единицы, как вы правильно заметили по поводу X(Y+1), приведет к числу P, которое может быть выражено меньшим числом единичек.

Comment: X и Y имеются в виду не 1ки, а простые множители 2,3,5. остальные рассматривать смысла нету, они выражаются меньшим числом 1 через эти.

Comment: @yura ivanov Я не вдавался в глубокое изучение математической теории данной задачи, я предложил брутфорсный алгоритм, который ищет полным перебором.  
Всецело согласен, что Ваш алгоритм верен (один из плюсов на Вашем ответа и мой тоже), я лишь хотел предложить легко реализуемый с минимумом затрат мозга алгоритм.

Comment: @ReinRaus, да это я так, дополнил просто. На самом деле, такие задачи предназначены в основном для закрепления изученного материала. Т.е. например, на лекции рассказали какую-то тему про численные методы и сразу лабы выдали по этой теме. Математическая составляющая часто берется "из кармана" доцента. В редких случаях (олимпиады, в частности) эта составляющая должна приходить озарением (элементарные мат. модели), а алгоритм представляется довольно непростым. Брутфорс как в первом случае, так и во втором редко является правильным решением.

Answer (score 10):

Оптимальных записей, как нетрудно догадаться, может быть довольно много. Например, число 11 можно записать как `1+2*5` (как вариант `1+2*(2*2+1)`) и как `3*3+2` (количество единиц будет одним и тем же).

Один из вариантов. без доказательства, надо аккуратно вывести почему такой вариант тоже оптимален (лениво):

Любое число делится либо на 2 либо на 3, либо с остатком 1 на 2 или на 3.
Ну и будем рекурсивно проверять частное на остаток от деления на 2 и на 3, отдавая предпочтение делителю без остатка. Т.е. если делится на 2, то делим на 2. Если не делится на 2, а делится на 3, то делим на 3. Если не делится ни на то ни на другое, то вычитаем 1 и делим на 2. Если число (или число без 1) делится на 2 и на 3 одновременно, то приоритет тут не важен, в дальнейшем, когда кратное перестанет быть четным, на 3 поделим все равно, этот делитель никуда не денется.

например:

```
    11 => 2*(5)+1 => 2*(2*(2)+1)+1
    126 => 2*(63) => 2*(3*(21)) => 2*(3*(3*(7))) =>... =>2*(3*(3*(2*3+1)))
```

ЗЫ Время работы O(logN)

Answer (score 3):

Решение через простое ДП: если мы знаем ответ для  ***< N***  , то ответ для N – это минимум из: (ответ для **a** + ответ для **N/a**), а также (ответ для **a** + ответ для *N-*a**). Под плюсом подразумевается сложение строк, хотя я бы для каждой позиции запоминал, откуда мы приходим, чтобы потом рекурсивно восстановить ответ за O(N).

Сложность алгоритма O(N*N).

Answer (score 2):

Реализация алгоритма из моего комментария чуть выше, алгоритм последовательно перебирает все числа до нужного, ища оптимальное представление записи.
Алгоритм рассматривает варианты

```
i+j
i*j
i+j+1
i*j+1
```

Не буду браться за математическое доказательство, но скорее всего другие представления не дадут оптимизации длины записи. Хотя не буду это утверждать.

```
def getArray(maxN):
    res={} # [ключ]=сумма единиц, строка представления
    res[1]=[1, "1"]                    #стартовые значения
    res[2]=[2, "1+1"]
    for current in xrange(3, maxN):    #текущее обрабытываемое число
        minims=[current+1, 0, 0, 0]    #[минимальное значение, i, j, метод]
        for i in xrange(1, current):
            for j in xrange(1, current):
                values=[ # варианты представлений записи
                    i+j,
                    i*j,
                    i+j+1,
                    i*j+1,
                ]
                for k in range(4):
                    # если число можно выразить через i и j, и сумма единиц меньше, чем ранее найденные
                    if values[k]==current and res[i][0]+res[j][0]+int(k>1)<minims[0]:
                        minims=[res[i][0]+res[j][0]+int(k>1), i, j, k]
        res[current]=[minims[0], getSummaryString(res[minims[1]], res[minims[2]], minims[3])]
    return res

# создает строку представления числа
def getSummaryString(val1, val2, method):
    if method%2==0:
        res= val1[1]+"+"+val2[1]
    else:
        res= "("+val1[1]+")("+val2[1]+")"
    if method>1:
        res+="+1"
    return res

arr=getArray(40)
print arr
```

Результат

```
{1: [1, '1'], 2: [2, '1+1'], 3: [3, '1+1+1'], 4: [4, '1+1+1+1'], 5: [5, '1+1+1+1+1'], 6: [5, '(1+1)(1+1+1)'], 7: [6, '1+(1+1)(1+1+1)'], 8: [6, '(1+1)(1+1+1+1)'], 9: [6, '(1+1+1)(1+1+1)'], 10: [7, '1+(1+1+1)(1+1+1)'], 11: [8, '1+(1+1+1)(1+1+1)+1'], 12: [7, '(1+1)((1+1)(1+1+1))'], 13: [8, '1+(1+1)((1+1)(1+1+1))'], 14: [8, '(1+1)(1+(1+1)(1+1+1))'], 15: [8, '(1+1+1)(1+1+1+1+1)'], 16: [8, '(1+1)((1+1)(1+1+1+1))'], 17: [9, '1+(1+1)((1+1)(1+1+1+1))'], 18: [8, '(1+1)((1+1+1)(1+1+1))'], 19: [9, '1+(1+1)((1+1+1)(1+1+1))'], 20: [9, '(1+1)(1+(1+1+1)(1+1+1))'], 21: [9, '(1+1+1)(1+(1+1)(1+1+1))'], 22: [10, '1+(1+1+1)(1+(1+1)(1+1+1))'], 23: [11, '1+(1+1+1)(1+(1+1)(1+1+1))+1'], 24: [9, '(1+1)((1+1)((1+1)(1+1+1)))'], 25: [10, '1+(1+1)((1+1)((1+1)(1+1+1)))'], 26: [10, '(1+1)(1+(1+1)((1+1)(1+1+1)))'], 27: [9, '(1+1+1)((1+1+1)(1+1+1))'], 28: [10, '1+(1+1+1)((1+1+1)(1+1+1))'], 29: [11, '1+(1+1+1)((1+1+1)(1+1+1))+1'], 30: [10, '(1+1)((1+1+1)(1+1+1+1+1))'], 31: [11, '1+(1+1)((1+1+1)(1+1+1+1+1))'], 32: [10, '(1+1)((1+1)((1+1)(1+1+1+1)))'], 33: [11, '1+(1+1)((1+1)((1+1)(1+1+1+1)))'], 34: [11, '(1+1)(1+(1+1)((1+1)(1+1+1+1)))'], 35: [11, '(1+1+1+1+1)(1+(1+1)(1+1+1))'], 36: [10, '(1+1)((1+1)((1+1+1)(1+1+1)))'], 37: [11, '1+(1+1)((1+1)((1+1+1)(1+1+1)))'], 38: [11, '(1+1)(1+(1+1)((1+1+1)(1+1+1)))'], 39: [11, '(1+1+1)(1+(1+1)((1+1)(1+1+1)))']}
```

Путей к повышению производительности этого кода- десятки, я не стал этого делать, так как это лишь демонстрация.

Comment: Извините кстати за Python, но подобные алгоритмы реализовать на таких языках как С это ппц как много кода.

Answer (score 1):

```
f(n) = Min((для любого i, что n % i == 0: f(i) + f(n / i) + 1), f(n - 1) + 1)
```

**Перенесено из комментария**.

```
int A[100];

int f(int n) {
    if (A[n] == -1) {
        A[n] = n;

        for (int i = 2 ; i <= n / 2 ; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                A[n] = min(A[n], f(i) + f(n / i));
            }
        }

        A[n] = min(A[n], 1 + f(n - 1));
    }

    return A[n];
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    memset(A, -1, sizeof A);
    A[1] = 1;
    cout << f(n);
}
```

Вот код, сверху подсказка была (рекуррентное соотношение).

Comment: а можно чуть опишете строчку? А то я не разобрался в нем. Эта функция. Понял. Но это вы как подсказку дали или как код? @baklajancho

Comment: Перенесено в ответ.

Comment: А вы такой код в действии проверяли? хотя бы на числах более 10000?

и в цикле тогда хотя бы лучше использовать условие не i<=n/2 а что-то вроде i*i<=n (больше корня простых делителей нет, и да зачем проверять на какие-то числа кроме простых)

Вообще моё имхо (задачу какую-то с подобной идеей на acm.timus.ru решал) по-моему как-то все завязано на 3 (с ней лучшие результаты получаются)

Вообще если ТС скажет откуда задача мог бы посмотреть

Comment: А можно конкретные результаты работы алгоритма в студию ? Не совсем понял основную мысль поиска :(

Comment: Строка A[n] = min(A[n], 1 + f(n - 1)) не верна: надо заменить на что-то вроде
    A[n] = min(A[n], min([f(x) + f(n - x) for x in range(1, n // 2 + 1)]))

Answer (score 1):

Как несложно догадаться минимальное количество 1 получится в случае если число будет разложено на минимальные составляющие `+/-` соседние числа с учетом операций сложения/вычитания. Скажем тот же 99 - раскладывается так:

```
11*9=99 //20 единичек
3*3*11=99 //17 единичек
2*2*5*5-1=99 //15 единичек (**бинго!**)
7*7*2+1=99 //17 единичек
```

Очевидно, в любом случае наиболее эффективно разложение на простые числа, потому что если разложение будет не на простое число - то количество единичек будет больше (надеюсь это понятно).

Теперь по алгоритму. Действуем так (далее псевдокод):

1. Пишем функцию разложения числа на простые числа - скажем `int[] a=getPrimes(int x)`. При этом количество единичек после разложения считается просто: это сумма по всем элементам массива `s[0]=sum(a[])`
2. Далее запускаем небольшой цикл который +/- "болтает/девиирует" вокруг нашего x типа: `getPrimes(x+i)` - количество единичек здесь будет `s[i]=sum(a[])+i`
3. Выбираем минимальное из `s[i]`
4. Значение уровня девиации `i` - опять же очевидно, должно быть не больше 2, 3

Comment: минусы нельзя. и 99 раскладывается в 14 единичек. 3*3*(2*(2*2+1)+1)

Answer (score 0):

Ну, можно попробовать использовать такой метод( рассмотрим на том же числе 99 ):

```
Вот нам дается число 99.
Далее мы будем последовательно делить данное число(99) на делители в диапазоне [2,9]. Почему так? Это наиболее оптимальный вариант! 
Вот мы ищем делитель, когда частное получится целым(исключение-простое число). Ищем от большего, т.е от 9. Если число менее 9, то ищем от двух.
Нашли! Это 9! (1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)
Далее берем наше частное - 11.
Проводим с ним такую же операцию. Нашли оптимальный "делитель"...но 11-простое число, поэтому берем делитель ((X-1)/2). X - наше 11 в данном случае. В итоге получаем "подвыражение" (1+1+1+1+1)*(1+1).
И берем наш остаток - 1.
```

Помогайте дальше =)

Comment: А я сам тоже додумался на делители, **только** вот как найти их??? Например 99 делится и на 9, и на 6, и на 3. Как найти то оптимальный? Точнее, как выбрать из диапазона? Тогда он должен все делить на [2, 9], а потом сравнивать все. Где будет ответ наименьший, то и брать? А не долго ли слишком? =/ Или же беру 87. А как в этом случае? @Asen